# php list() undefined behaviour

Tags: php, undefined-behavior

I came across this line:

```
list($diff, $current, $concurrent) = $diff;
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) states that this should result in undefined behaviour. What are the possible variants of this behaviour? Variable $diff is array, containing 3 elements with variable content.

This line is part of application that contains a bug and author of this line is unavailable. Though I am almost sure that it is not what I am looking for, it would be nice to be 100% sure.
I am using PHP 5.6.25 as FPM/FastCGI.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit the application code? If so `$array = $diff; list($diff, $current, $concurrent) = $array;` will eliminate any undefined behavior.

Comment: It's undefined for a reason, it's likely to have a different effect depending on your version/operating system etc. You are overwriting `$diff` with `$diff` whilst it's been evaluated. Perhaps doing what @Steve suggested or changing the `list($diff...` variable will help.

Comment: Would be nice if I got 2 more comments on improving my question, instead of 2 downvotes.

Comment: @Steve Of course I will remove potentially undefined behaviour, but I would like to know the exact possibilities. Hope I am not asking for too much.

Comment: @R.Chappell Can you give a couple of actual examples on how can this or similar thing work differently?

Comment: No, but I can give you a definition of `undefined`: without fixed limits; indefinite in form, extent, or application. Meaning there is an indefinite amount of ways it can work differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation for list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) also states:

> In PHP 5, list() assigns the values starting with the right-most parameter. In PHP 7, list() starts with the left-most parameter.

In other words: This line might work as intended in PHP 5, because the variable `$diff` that appears on both sides is the last variable to get assigned. However, in PHP 7 the `$diff` variable gets assigned first, so `$diff` has already changed by the time the assignments for `$current` and `$concurrent` are done.

In general I think the hint about undefined behaviour relates to the fact that you cannot rely on certain assignments to yield the expected results, if a variable appears on both sides of the `=` sign. A workaround for the issue could look like this:

```
list($temp, $current, $concurrent) = $diff;
$diff = $temp;
unset($temp);
```

This way you avoid the undefined behaviour.